# How to export Resource Pool (Busy State) in each simulation run

Tags: resources, anylogic, pool, resource-utilization

Wondering if there is a function to export resource pool (busy state) onto e.g. Excel over the whole simulation run time? I am using Time Stack Chart at the moment (see photo), but I could only copy a snapshot of the utilisation onto Excel, not the whole simulation duration.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsopG.jpg)

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you want to store externally? Question is not really clear. Feel free to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and return to improve it :)

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't clear.

Comment: For example Simulation Time 200, the system needs 15 operators (as shown at the photo), Simulation Time 250, the system needs 12 operators. I would like to export these statistics onto Excel over the whole simulation run duration from Time 0 to e.g. Time 2000.

Comment: Currently, I am thinking to create a dummy "source - delay - sink" and send agent for every 60 mins interval in order to write to excel to capture no of seized operators at every T 60 mins.

Comment: Wondering if Anylogic has any built-in function to do the same so not to slow down my model.

Comment: sorry, can you re-edit the question to include your comments and make it clear? :)